# php function argument FILE type error

Tags: php, file, function

I try send a file into a php function

link of function:
  [here is that function](https://gist.github.com/giorrrgio/3904046#file-imagineresizer-php)

or:
    public function resize(File $file, $destination)
        {
           ...
        }

I try this ways:

```
$IMAGES_DIR = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$object->resize('http://root.com/pic.jpg',$IMAGES_DIR);
```

or

```
$object->resize($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/pic.jpg',$IMAGES_DIR);
```

but I got this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Acme\MyBundle\Service\ImagineResizer::resize() must be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, string given, called in
>   C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\root.com\webroot\images.php on line 20 and
>   defined in
>   C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\root.com\webroot\core\images\functions.php
>   on line 24

Comment: By the looks of the error message that function doesn't expect a file path but `an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create file object first.

Try this:

```
$file = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File('http://root.com/pic.jpg');
$object->resize($file ,$IMAGES_DIR);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer without knowing the code inside your resize function.  However, it appears that you are simply using a filename as your first parameter but your function is expecting what you  have type-hinted: a Symphony "File" object.

You need to create such an object outside of the function and pass that instead of a filename string.

Comment: thanks but code there is in the question. I linked it. please check it :)

Comment: yes just saw that!  Sorry -- I modified my answer. Looks like gellu's answer above also provided more info on how to do that exactly